# What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, clone

What is the most efficient way to clone a JavaScript object? I've seen `obj = eval(uneval(o));` being used, but [that's non-standard and only supported by Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/uneval).
 I've done things like `obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o));` but question the efficiency. 
 I've also seen recursive copying functions with various flaws.

I'm surprised no canonical solution exists.

Comment: Eval is not evil. Using eval poorly is. If you are afraid of its side effects you are using it wrong. The side effects you fear are the reasons to use it. Did any one by the way actually answer your question?

Comment: Cloning objects is a tricky business, especially with custom objects of arbitrary collections. Which probably why there is no out-of-the box way to do it.

Comment: `eval()` is generally a bad idea because [many Javascript engine's optimisers have to turn off when dealing with variables that are set via `eval`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447519/can-eval-optimize). Just having `eval()` in your code can lead to worse performance.

Comment: Note that `JSON` method will loose any Javascript types that have no equivalent in JSON. For example: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({a:null,b:NaN,c:Infinity,d:undefined,e:function(){},f:Number,g:false}))` will generate `{a: null, b: null, c: null, g: false}`

Comment: The react community has introduced [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper)

Answer (score 5882, accepted):

## Native deep cloning

There's now a JS standard called ["structured cloning"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone), that works experimentally in Node 11 and later, will land in browsers, and which has [polyfills for existing systems](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ungap/structured-clone).

```
structuredClone(value)
```

If needed, loading the polyfill first:

```
import structuredClone from '@ungap/structured-clone';
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript/10916838#10916838) for more details.

## Older answers

### Fast cloning with data loss - JSON.parse/stringify

If you do not use `Date`s, functions, `undefined`, `Infinity`, RegExps, Maps, Sets, Blobs, FileLists, ImageDatas, sparse Arrays, Typed Arrays or other complex types within your object, a very simple one liner to deep clone an object is:

`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))`

```js
const a = {
  string: 'string',
  number: 123,
  bool: false,
  nul: null,
  date: new Date(),  // stringified
  undef: undefined,  // lost
  inf: Infinity,  // forced to 'null'
  re: /.*/,  // lost
}
console.log(a);
console.log(typeof a.date);  // Date object
const clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));
console.log(clone);
console.log(typeof clone.date);  // result of .toISOString()
```

See [Corban's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript/5344074#5344074) for benchmarks.

### Reliable cloning using a library

Since cloning objects is not trivial (complex types, circular references, function etc.), most major libraries provide function to clone objects. **Don't reinvent the wheel** - if you're already using a library, check if it has an object cloning function. For example,

- lodash - [`cloneDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep); can be imported separately via the [lodash.clonedeep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.clonedeep) module and is probably your best choice if you're not already using a library that provides a deep cloning function
- Ramda - [`clone`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#clone)
- AngularJS - [`angular.copy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)
- jQuery - [`jQuery.extend(true, { }, oldObject)`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/#jQuery-extend-deep-target-object1-objectN); `.clone()` only clones DOM elements
- just library - [`just-clone`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/just-clone); Part of a library of zero-dependency npm modules that do just do one thing.
  Guilt-free utilities for every occasion.

Comment: Beware!
`var A = { b: [ { a: [ 1, 2, 3], b: [4, 5, 6], c: [7, 8, 9] } ] };
B = Object.assign( {}, A );
delete B.b[0].b;`
It will also modify object A !

Comment: @GabrielHautclocq what's the solution in this case?

Comment: @GabrielHautclocq You have just discovered what a "shallow copy" means. "@medBouzid" The solution is to "deep copy" the object, instead of shallow copying.

Comment: I was just demonstrating by example that you cannot use Object.assign for deep cloning an object.

Comment: `Object.assign()` is indeed useless if your object to copy contains arrays in it, especially arrays of objects. Just found that out the hard way...

Comment: @Gabriel Hautclocq this is because `A.b` or `B.b` are both referring to the same object in the memory. if `A` had a property with a non-object value (like numbers or strings), it'll be copied normally. But when a property containing an object value is copied, it is copied by-reference, not by-value. Also, keep in mind that an Array is an object in JS. proof: `typeof [] == 'object' && [] instanceof Array`

Comment: @Unicornist Yes and that's why Object.assign does not answer the question which is: "What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?". So at least it should NOT be presented as an ES6 solution for deep cloning. The title "ES6" is misleading, at least it should be changed to reflect that this is not a deep cloning method. The "shallow" word is easy to overlook and a lot of people just take the simplest solution they find in Stack Overflow without reading everything. It is dangerous to rely on Object.assign for object cloning. Hence my remark.

Comment: I used a library called really fast deep clone:
https://github.com/davidmarkclements/rfdc

Worked really well for me.

Comment: If you experience problems like in first comment, https://github.com/davidmarkclements/rfdc also will make "shallow copy", you'll need to enable option `proto: true`,

Comment: I was scratching my head debugging again & again & turned out File object wasn't being copied with this method & it was being dropped during the deepclone.

Comment: @GabrielHautclocq:
1. the proposed solution you're struggling with comes under ES6 (_shallow_ copy). The behaviour you highlight refers to _deep_ copy. Shallow copy only copies the values for the immediate level of the object. If some values are themselves non-atomic, they will be copied by reference.
2. The title ES6 is *NOT* misleading at all. ES6 introduces destructuring as in `{...A1}`, which is better than any `for`-based solution by a landslide.

I have a case of a Python-dictionary-like object, where the values are all boolean. The shallow `{...obj}` alternative works like a charm.

Comment: @Ricardo Surely you can see the history of the answer to see that "(shallow copy)" has been added after "ES6", after I wrote my comment. It's now more clear that this is a shallow copy.

Comment: Lodash has deprecated per method packages: https://lodash.com/per-method-packages

Comment: old news or whatever, but I just had the pleasure of learning this particular part of the jasonstringifyclone: 'If you do not use Dates, etc, etc...' sigh... now rethinking...

Comment: Node's full support for structuredClone begins in v17

Comment: `structuredClone(...)` is now available in all the meaningful browsers. It would be helpful to see a usage example, especially concerning transferable objects. I'd also argue that `JSON.stringify / parse` can handle dates, you just need to use the reviver (parse) and the replacer (stringify)

Comment: For me the simple `const element = document.createElement(name);
    for (const key in object) {
        element[key] = object[key];
    }
    return element;` would do the job, and i bet it's the fastest

Comment: The just-clone library was simple to use and worked well for me.  The whole just-xxx library is a great idea

Comment: This is not Javascript! This is Node! People should stop answer Javascript question assuming Javascript-based languages like Node and JQuery(argh)! Where is the Vanilla Javascript answer?

Comment: Note that Iglesias' example is one where `structuredClone` wouldn't even be usable: it cannot create copies of DOM nodes and will throw `DOMException: HTML(...)Element object could not be cloned`. It, unfortunately, does not fall through to `cloneNode(true)` when DOM nodes are encountered.

Answer (score 2496):

Checkout this benchmark: http://jsben.ch/#/bWfk9

In my previous tests where speed was a main concern I found

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

to be the slowest way to deep clone an object (it is slower than [jQuery.extend](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) with `deep` flag set true by 10-20%).

jQuery.extend is pretty fast when the `deep` flag is set to `false` (shallow clone). It is a good option, because it includes some extra logic for type validation and doesn't copy over undefined properties, etc., but this will also slow you down a little.

If you know the structure of the objects you are trying to clone or can avoid deep nested arrays you can write a simple `for (var i in obj)` loop to clone your object while checking hasOwnProperty and it will be much much faster than jQuery.

Lastly if you are attempting to clone a known object structure in a hot loop you can get MUCH MUCH MORE PERFORMANCE by simply in-lining the clone procedure and manually constructing the object.

JavaScript trace engines suck at optimizing `for..in` loops and checking hasOwnProperty will slow you down as well. Manual clone when speed is an absolute must.

```
var clonedObject = {
  knownProp: obj.knownProp,
  ..
}
```

Beware using the `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` method on `Date` objects - `JSON.stringify(new Date())` returns a string representation of the date in ISO format, which `JSON.parse()` **doesn't** convert back to a `Date` object. [See this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491938/issues-with-date-when-using-json-stringify-and-json-parse/11491993#11491993).

Additionally, please note that, in Chrome 65 at least, native cloning is not the way to go. According to JSPerf, performing native cloning by creating a new function is nearly **800x** slower than using JSON.stringify which is incredibly fast all the way across the board.

**[Update for ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)**

If you are using Javascript ES6 try this native method for cloning or shallow copy.

```
Object.assign({}, obj);
```

Comment: Note that there are 2 mistakes in your bench: first, it compares some shallow cloning (lodash `_.clone` and `Object.assign`) to some deep cloning (`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`). Secondly, it says "deep clone" for lodash but it does a shallow clone instead.

Comment: Note that when testing in the same benchmarking tool, **object spread** `let obj2 = {...obj}` appears to be more efficient than `Object.assign()`. Approximately ~20% faster.

Comment: Note, re Object.assign({}, obj} - this is a shallow copy not a deep clone.  This means that if a property is itself an object you only get a reference.

Comment: +1000 for inline cloning. I had hardcoded in a list of the known properties for my object and was looping over them, which gave me about 3000 copies per millisecond. Once I got rid of the loop and wrote out every property in an object literal, that went up to about 2 million copies per millisecond. Absolutely insane speed gains, I never realized loops were that slow.

Answer (score 666):

## Structured Cloning

**2022 update:** The [`structuredClone` global function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) is already available in Firefox 94, Node 17 and Deno 1.14

The HTML standard includes [**an internal structured cloning/serialization algorithm**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/structured-data.html#safe-passing-of-structured-data) that can create deep clones of objects. It is still limited to certain built-in types, but in addition to the few types supported by JSON it also supports Dates, RegExps, Maps, Sets, Blobs, FileLists, ImageDatas, sparse Arrays, Typed Arrays, and probably more in the future. It also preserves references within the cloned data, allowing it to support cyclical and recursive structures that would cause errors for JSON.

### Support in Node.js:

The [`structuredClone` global function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) is provided by Node 17.0:

```
const clone = structuredClone(original);
```

Previous versions: The `v8` module in Node.js (as of Node 11) [exposes the structured serialization API directly](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#v8_serialization_api), but this functionality is still marked as "experimental", and subject to change or removal in future versions. If you're using a compatible version, cloning an object is as simple as:

```js
const v8 = require('v8');

const structuredClone = obj => {
  return v8.deserialize(v8.serialize(obj));
};
```

### Direct Support in Browsers: Available in Firefox 94

The [`structuredClone` global function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) will soon be provided by all major browsers (having previously been discussed in [whatwg/html#793 on GitHub](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/793)). It looks / will look like this:

```js
const clone = structuredClone(original);
```

Until this is shipped, browsers' structured clone implementations are only exposed indirectly.

### Asynchronous Workaround: Usable.

The lower-overhead way to create a structured clone with existing APIs is to post the data through one port of a [MessageChannels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageChannel). The other port will emit a `message` event with a structured clone of the attached `.data`. Unfortunately, listening for these events is necessarily asynchronous, and the synchronous alternatives are less practical.

```js
class StructuredCloner {
  constructor() {
    this.pendingClones_ = new Map();
    this.nextKey_ = 0;
    
    const channel = new MessageChannel();
    this.inPort_ = channel.port1;
    this.outPort_ = channel.port2;
    
    this.outPort_.onmessage = ({data: {key, value}}) => {
      const resolve = this.pendingClones_.get(key);
      resolve(value);
      this.pendingClones_.delete(key);
    };
    this.outPort_.start();
  }

  cloneAsync(value) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      const key = this.nextKey_++;
      this.pendingClones_.set(key, resolve);
      this.inPort_.postMessage({key, value});
    });
  }
}

const structuredCloneAsync = window.structuredCloneAsync =
    StructuredCloner.prototype.cloneAsync.bind(new StructuredCloner);
```

#### Example Use:

```js
const main = async () => {
  const original = { date: new Date(), number: Math.random() };
  original.self = original;

  const clone = await structuredCloneAsync(original);

  // They're different objects:
  console.assert(original !== clone);
  console.assert(original.date !== clone.date);

  // They're cyclical:
  console.assert(original.self === original);
  console.assert(clone.self === clone);

  // They contain equivalent values:
  console.assert(original.number === clone.number);
  console.assert(Number(original.date) === Number(clone.date));
  
  console.log("Assertions complete.");
};

main();
```

### Synchronous Workarounds: Awful!

There are no good options for creating structured clones synchronously. Here are a couple of impractical hacks instead.

`history.pushState()` and `history.replaceState()` both create a structured clone of their first argument, and assign that value to `history.state`. You can use this to create a structured clone of any object like this:

```js
const structuredClone = obj => {
  const oldState = history.state;
  history.replaceState(obj, null);
  const clonedObj = history.state;
  history.replaceState(oldState, null);
  return clonedObj;
};
```

#### Example Use:

```js
'use strict';

const main = () => {
  const original = { date: new Date(), number: Math.random() };
  original.self = original;

  const clone = structuredClone(original);
  
  // They're different objects:
  console.assert(original !== clone);
  console.assert(original.date !== clone.date);

  // They're cyclical:
  console.assert(original.self === original);
  console.assert(clone.self === clone);

  // They contain equivalent values:
  console.assert(original.number === clone.number);
  console.assert(Number(original.date) === Number(clone.date));
  
  console.log("Assertions complete.");
};

const structuredClone = obj => {
  const oldState = history.state;
  history.replaceState(obj, null);
  const clonedObj = history.state;
  history.replaceState(oldState, null);
  return clonedObj;
};

main();
```

Though synchronous, this can be extremely slow. It incurs all of the overhead associated with manipulating the browser history. Calling this method repeatedly can cause Chrome to become temporarily unresponsive.

The [`Notification` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/Notification) creates a structured clone of its associated data. It also attempts to display a browser notification to the user, but this will silently fail unless you have requested notification permission. In case you have the permission for other purposes, we'll immediately close the notification we've created.

```js
const structuredClone = obj => {
  const n = new Notification('', {data: obj, silent: true});
  n.onshow = n.close.bind(n);
  return n.data;
};
```

#### Example Use:

```js
'use strict';

const main = () => {
  const original = { date: new Date(), number: Math.random() };
  original.self = original;

  const clone = structuredClone(original);
  
  // They're different objects:
  console.assert(original !== clone);
  console.assert(original.date !== clone.date);

  // They're cyclical:
  console.assert(original.self === original);
  console.assert(clone.self === clone);

  // They contain equivalent values:
  console.assert(original.number === clone.number);
  console.assert(Number(original.date) === Number(clone.date));
  
  console.log("Assertions complete.");
};

const structuredClone = obj => {
  const n = new Notification('', {data: obj, silent: true});
  n.close();
  return n.data;
};

main();
```

Comment: This is just so wrong! That API is not meant to be used this way.

Comment: As the guy who implemented pushState in Firefox, I feel an odd mix of pride and revulsion at this hack.  Well done, guys.

Comment: pushState or Notification hack does not work for some object types like Function

Comment: @ShishirArora You're right, I just tried it, it throws a 'Uncaught DOMException: The object could not be cloned.' This is also true for the Notification hack.

Comment: Would anyone happen to know if the native v8 Structured Cloning is susceptible to prototype pollution?

Comment: **April 2022 update:** `structuredClone` is available in FF 94+, Chrome 98+ and Safari 15.4+ and Edge 98+, so in all current versions of the major browsers!

Comment: Abuse of API like the above (no offense at @Jeremy's valiant attempts to show solutions) will continue as long as HTML authoring committees are fundamentally unable to design APIs of quality and continue churning out APIs that are broken-by-design. For instance, the structured clone algorithm defines a procedure that is rigid (hardly extendible by a script, say) and at the same time leaves too much to the user agent. Firefox, f.e., is unable to clone `Error` objects, for instance -- but MDN proudly states it supports `structuredClone` and friends, although this is a manner of interpretation.

Comment: @ArmenMichaeli THIS. HTML authoring committees are fundamentally unable to design APIs of quality
It is appalling how they manage to so such a bad job over and over again. 
It has been done in different tech stacks decades ago.

Everything in JS is an object. There is NO vanilla 1 liner which deep clones an object. This is the definition of insanity. It should be as simple as = is by reference and := is by value or something like that.

Comment: `structuredClone` is far less performant than other solutions offered here, like using Object.assign or lodash cloneDeep. The question specifically asked for it, so it is important to mention. This may change as native implementation do change - but for now, it's the worst option.

Comment: @SnirD Object.assign does a shallow copy.

Answer (score 569):

Assuming that you have only properties and not any functions in your object, you can  just use:

```
var newObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldObject));
```

Comment: *functions* and **dates** as well

Comment: Fails for objects with Circular properties

Comment: or Sets or other non-JSON-serializable properties

Comment: IMHO I think this is the best way to clone a data object. Especially when u are dealing with data fetched from an API and state management. I believe that if you need to clone an object that was created with native Javascript constructs (functions, dates, NaN...) there is something wrong or most probably you do not need to clone it.

Comment: This is inefficient for types like **NaN, Infinity, undefined** etc. JSON.stringify converts them to null. Reference: **JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({a:null,b:undefined}))** equals **{a: null}**.

Answer (score 380):

If there wasn't any builtin one, you could try:

```
function clone(obj) {
    if (obj === null || typeof (obj) !== 'object' || 'isActiveClone' in obj)
        return obj;

    if (obj instanceof Date)
        var temp = new obj.constructor(); //or new Date(obj);
    else
        var temp = obj.constructor();

    for (var key in obj) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
            obj['isActiveClone'] = null;
            temp[key] = clone(obj[key]);
            delete obj['isActiveClone'];
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain `isActiveClone` part a bit?

Comment: It seems to track circular references.
E.g.:
`const a = {};
a['selfref'] = a;
a['text'] = 'something';
alert(a.selfref.text);`

If you tried to clone the above `a` object without the `isActiveClone` part, you'd end up in an infinite recursion (because of the recursive `clone()` call on property `selfref`).

Comment: One the best answers here that handle `Arrays` and `Cyclic References ` as well as clean code with acceptable speed (performance)

Answer (score 169):

## The efficient way to clone(not deep-clone) an object in one line of code

An [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method is part of the ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) standard and does exactly what you need.

```
var clone = Object.assign({}, obj);
```

> The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object.

[Read more...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

The **polyfill** to support older browsers:

```
if (!Object.assign) {
  Object.defineProperty(Object, 'assign', {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value: function(target) {
      'use strict';
      if (target === undefined || target === null) {
        throw new TypeError('Cannot convert first argument to object');
      }

      var to = Object(target);
      for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var nextSource = arguments[i];
        if (nextSource === undefined || nextSource === null) {
          continue;
        }
        nextSource = Object(nextSource);

        var keysArray = Object.keys(nextSource);
        for (var nextIndex = 0, len = keysArray.length; nextIndex < len; nextIndex++) {
          var nextKey = keysArray[nextIndex];
          var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(nextSource, nextKey);
          if (desc !== undefined && desc.enumerable) {
            to[nextKey] = nextSource[nextKey];
          }
        }
      }
      return to;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This doesn't recursively copy so doesn't really offer a solution to the problem of cloning an object.

Comment: This method worked, although I tested a few and _.extend({}, (obj)) was BY FAR the fastest: 20x faster than JSON.parse and 60% faster than Object.assign, for example. It copies all sub-objects quite well.

Comment: @mwhite there is a difference between clone and deep-clone. This answer does in fact clone, but it doesn't deep-clone.

Comment: the question was about recursive copies. Object.assign, as well as the given custom assign, do not copy recursively

Comment: This answer isn't a deep-clone and isn't what the question is about.

Answer (score 136):

**Deep copy by performance:**

Ranked from best to worst, based on benchmarks
https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/17502/0/deep-copy-comparison

- spread operator `...` (primitive arrays - only)
- `slice()` (primitive arrays - only)
- `splice(0)` (primitive arrays - only)
- `concat()` (primitive arrays - only)
- `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` (primitive and literal arrays - only)
- custom function, as seen below (any array)
- Lodash's `_.cloneDeep()` (any array)
- jQuery's `$.extend()` (any array)
- Underscore's `_.clone()` (primitive and literal arrays - only)

Where:

- primitives = strings, numbers, and booleans
- literals = object literals `{}`, array literals `[]`
- any = primitives, literals, and prototypes

**Deep copy an array of primitives:**

```js
let arr1a = [1, 'a', true];
```

To deep copy arrays with primitives only (i.e. numbers, strings, and booleans), reassignment, `slice()`, `concat()`, and Underscore's `clone()` can be used.

Where spread has the fastest performance:

```js
let arr1b = [...arr1a];
```

And where `slice()` has better performance than `splice(0)` and `concat()`

```js
let arr1d = arr1a.slice();
let arr1c = arr1a.splice(0);
let arr1e = arr1a.concat();
```

**Deep copy an array of primitive and object literals:**

```js
let arr2a = [1, 'a', true, {}, []];
let arr2b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr2a));
```

**Deep copy an array of primitive, object literals, and prototypes:**

```js
let arr3a = [1, 'a', true, {}, [], new Object()];
```

Write a custom function (has faster performance than jQuery `$.extend()`):

```js
function copy(aObject) {
  // Prevent undefined objects
  // if (!aObject) return aObject;

  let bObject = Array.isArray(aObject) ? [] : {};

  let value;
  for (const key in aObject) {

    // Prevent self-references to parent object
    // if (Object.is(aObject[key], aObject)) continue;
    
    value = aObject[key];

    bObject[key] = (typeof value === "object") ? copy(value) : value;
  }

  return bObject;
}

let arr3b = copy(arr3a);
```

Or use third-party utility functions:

```js
let arr3c = $.extend(true, [], arr3a); // jQuery
let arr3d = _.cloneDeep(arr3a); // Lodash
```

Comment: With for-in loop you should use ```hasOwnProperty``` to exclude inherited properties. I use (possibly even faster) plain for loop over ```Object.keys```.

Comment: In a deep copy, wouldn't you want to copy the inherited properties as well? Also, note that invoking the `hasOwnProperty` method, creates a performance hit (pushing the function call on and off the stack, and executing the method code) for every key.

Comment: Most of these are not deep clones at all, and therefore doesn't make sense to benchmark them against eachother.

Comment: in my tests, the `slice()` is very faster than `splice(0)`, although both of them are shallow copy

Comment: @S.Serpooshan - In agreement, answer has been updated based on the following benchmarks (https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/17502/0/deep-copy-comparison)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why this answer calls half of these "deep" copy methods when things like the spread operator, slice, etc. are all explicitly shallow copy mechanism.

Answer (score 123):

This is what I'm using:

```
function cloneObject(obj) {
    var clone = {};
    for(var i in obj) {
        if(typeof(obj[i])=="object" && obj[i] != null)
            clone[i] = cloneObject(obj[i]);
        else
            clone[i] = obj[i];
    }
    return clone;
}
```

Comment: Trying: var a = {b: 1, c: 3, d: { a: 10, g: 20, h: { today: new Date() }}};  Not working for me. But `Object.assign({}, a)` did.

Comment: Worse, try `let o = {}; o.o = o; cloneObject(o);`

Comment: Note: This will not work with `Date`s

Comment: This does not work for arrays, as it will turn them into objects: `{ a: ["foo", "bar"} }` will become `{ a { "0": "foo", "1": "bar" } }`.

Comment: I have extended this function for complex object but right now it won't support Date

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-vudfgn?file=index.ts

Answer (score 115):

Code:

```
// extends 'from' object with members from 'to'. If 'to' is null, a deep clone of 'from' is returned
function extend(from, to)
{
    if (from == null || typeof from != "object") return from;
    if (from.constructor != Object && from.constructor != Array) return from;
    if (from.constructor == Date || from.constructor == RegExp || from.constructor == Function ||
        from.constructor == String || from.constructor == Number || from.constructor == Boolean)
        return new from.constructor(from);

    to = to || new from.constructor();

    for (var name in from)
    {
        to[name] = typeof to[name] == "undefined" ? extend(from[name], null) : to[name];
    }

    return to;
}
```

Test:

```
var obj =
{
    date: new Date(),
    func: function(q) { return 1 + q; },
    num: 123,
    text: "asdasd",
    array: [1, "asd"],
    regex: new RegExp(/aaa/i),
    subobj:
    {
        num: 234,
        text: "asdsaD"
    }
}

var clone = extend(obj);
```

Comment: I don't this handles circular structures

Answer (score 103):

**Deep copying objects in JavaScript (I think the best and the simplest)**

**1. Using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));**

```
var obj = { 
  a: 1,
  b: { 
    c: 2
  }
}
var newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
obj.b.c = 20;
console.log(obj); // { a: 1, b: { c: 20 } }
console.log(newObj); // { a: 1, b: { c: 2 } }
```

**2.Using created method**

```
function cloneObject(obj) {
    var clone = {};
    for(var i in obj) {
        if(obj[i] != null &&  typeof(obj[i])=="object")
            clone[i] = cloneObject(obj[i]);
        else
            clone[i] = obj[i];
    }
    return clone;
}

var obj = { 
  a: 1,
  b: { 
    c: 2
  }
}
var newObj = cloneObject(obj);
obj.b.c = 20;

console.log(obj); // { a: 1, b: { c: 20 } }
console.log(newObj); // { a: 1, b: { c: 2 } }
```

**3. Using Lo-Dash's _.cloneDeep** link [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#cloneDeep)

```
var obj = { 
  a: 1,
  b: { 
    c: 2
  }
}

var newObj = _.cloneDeep(obj);
obj.b.c = 20;
console.log(obj); // { a: 1, b: { c: 20 } }
console.log(newObj); // { a: 1, b: { c: 2 } }
```

**4. Using Object.assign() method**

```
var obj = { 
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}

var newObj = _.clone(obj);
obj.b = 20;
console.log(obj); // { a: 1, b: 20 }
console.log(newObj); // { a: 1, b: 2 }
```

**BUT WRONG WHEN**

```
var obj = { 
  a: 1,
  b: { 
    c: 2
  }
}

var newObj = Object.assign({}, obj);
obj.b.c = 20;
console.log(obj); // { a: 1, b: { c: 20 } }
console.log(newObj); // { a: 1, b: { c: 20 } } --> WRONG
// Note: Properties on the prototype chain and non-enumerable properties cannot be copied.
```

**5.Using Underscore.js _.clone** link [Underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/#clone)

```
var obj = { 
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}

var newObj = _.clone(obj);
obj.b = 20;
console.log(obj); // { a: 1, b: 20 }
console.log(newObj); // { a: 1, b: 2 }
```

**BUT WRONG WHEN**

```
var obj = { 
  a: 1,
  b: { 
    c: 2
  }
}

var newObj = _.cloneDeep(obj);
obj.b.c = 20;
console.log(obj); // { a: 1, b: { c: 20 } }
console.log(newObj); // { a: 1, b: { c: 20 } } --> WRONG
// (Create a shallow-copied clone of the provided plain object. Any nested objects or arrays will be copied by reference, not duplicated.)
```

**JSBEN.CH Performance Benchmarking Playground 1~3 http://jsben.ch/KVQLd**
[image: Performance Deep copying objects in JavaScript]

Comment: Hey, your last example is wrong. In my opinion, you must use _clone and not _cloneDeep for the wrong example.

Comment: This created method (2.) won't work for arrays, will it?

Comment: Method #2 is vulnerable to prototype pollution, similar to what happened to lodash's `defaultsDeep`. It should not copy if `(i === '__proto__')`, and it should not copy if `(i === 'constuctor' && typeof obj[i] === 'function')`.

Answer (score 83):

Cloning an object was always a concern in JS, but it was all about before ES6, I list different ways of copying an object in JavaScript below, imagine you have the Object below and would like to have a deep copy of that:

```
var obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4};
```

There are few ways to copy this object, without changing the origin:

1. ES5+, Using a simple function to do the copy for you:

   ```
   function deepCopyObj(obj) {
       if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
       if (obj instanceof Date) {
           var copy = new Date();
           copy.setTime(obj.getTime());
           return copy;
       }
       if (obj instanceof Array) {
           var copy = [];
           for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++) {
               copy[i] = deepCopyObj(obj[i]);
           }
           return copy;
       }
       if (obj instanceof Object) {
           var copy = {};
           for (var attr in obj) {
               if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = deepCopyObj(obj[attr]);
           }
           return copy;
       }
       throw new Error("Unable to copy obj this object.");
   }
   ```
2. ES5+, using `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`.

   ```
   var deepCopyObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
   ```
3. Angular:

   ```
   var deepCopyObj = angular.copy(obj);
   ```
4. jQuery:

   ```
   var deepCopyObj = jQuery.extend(true, {}, obj);
   ```
5. Underscore.js & Lodash:

   ```
   var deepCopyObj = _.cloneDeep(obj); //latest version of Underscore.js makes shallow copy
   ```

Hope these help…

Answer (score 72):

```
var clone = function() {
    var newObj = (this instanceof Array) ? [] : {};
    for (var i in this) {
        if (this[i] && typeof this[i] == "object") {
            newObj[i] = this[i].clone();
        }
        else
        {
            newObj[i] = this[i];
        }
    }
    return newObj;
}; 

Object.defineProperty( Object.prototype, "clone", {value: clone, enumerable: false});
```

Answer (score 67):

There’s a [library (called “clone”)](https://github.com/pvorb/node-clone), that does this quite well. It provides the most complete recursive cloning/copying of arbitrary objects that I know of. It also supports circular references, which is not covered by the other answers, yet.

You can [find it on npm](https://npmjs.org/package/clone), too. It can be used for the browser as well as Node.js.

Here is an example on how to use it:

Install it with

```
npm install clone
```

or package it with [Ender](https://github.com/ender-js/Ender).

```
ender build clone [...]
```

You can also download the source code manually.

Then you can use it in your source code.

```
var clone = require('clone');

var a = { foo: { bar: 'baz' } };  // inital value of a
var b = clone(a);                 // clone a -> b
a.foo.bar = 'foo';                // change a

console.log(a);                   // { foo: { bar: 'foo' } }
console.log(b);                   // { foo: { bar: 'baz' } }
```

(Disclaimer: I’m the author of the library.)

Answer (score 57):

I know this is an old post, but I thought this may be of some help to the next person who stumbles along.

As long as you don't assign an object to anything it maintains no reference in memory.  So to make an object that you want to share among other objects, you'll have to create a factory like so:

```
var a = function(){
    return {
        father:'zacharias'
    };
},
b = a(),
c = a();
c.father = 'johndoe';
alert(b.father);
```

Comment: This isn't a deep clone of an existing object, this is just creating a new object.

Answer (score 50):

If you're using it, the [Underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/) library has a [clone](https://underscorejs.org/#clone) method.

```
var newObject = _.clone(oldObject);
```

Comment: This does a shallow copy, not a deep copy like OP is looking for.

Answer (score 48):

Here's a version of ConroyP's answer above that works even if the constructor has required parameters:

```
//If Object.create isn't already defined, we just do the simple shim,
//without the second argument, since that's all we need here
var object_create = Object.create;
if (typeof object_create !== 'function') {
    object_create = function(o) {
        function F() {}
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
}

function deepCopy(obj) {
    if(obj == null || typeof(obj) !== 'object'){
        return obj;
    }
    //make sure the returned object has the same prototype as the original
    var ret = object_create(obj.constructor.prototype);
    for(var key in obj){
        ret[key] = deepCopy(obj[key]);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

This function is also available in my [simpleoo](https://github.com/mbrowne/simpleoo.js) library.

**Edit:**

Here's a more robust version (thanks to Justin McCandless this now supports cyclic references as well):

```
/**
 * Deep copy an object (make copies of all its object properties, sub-properties, etc.)
 * An improved version of http://keithdevens.com/weblog/archive/2007/Jun/07/javascript.clone
 * that doesn't break if the constructor has required parameters
 * 
 * It also borrows some code from http://stackoverflow.com/a/11621004/560114
 */ 
function deepCopy(src, /* INTERNAL */ _visited, _copiesVisited) {
    if(src === null || typeof(src) !== 'object'){
        return src;
    }

    //Honor native/custom clone methods
    if(typeof src.clone == 'function'){
        return src.clone(true);
    }

    //Special cases:
    //Date
    if(src instanceof Date){
        return new Date(src.getTime());
    }
    //RegExp
    if(src instanceof RegExp){
        return new RegExp(src);
    }
    //DOM Element
    if(src.nodeType && typeof src.cloneNode == 'function'){
        return src.cloneNode(true);
    }

    // Initialize the visited objects arrays if needed.
    // This is used to detect cyclic references.
    if (_visited === undefined){
        _visited = [];
        _copiesVisited = [];
    }

    // Check if this object has already been visited
    var i, len = _visited.length;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        // If so, get the copy we already made
        if (src === _visited[i]) {
            return _copiesVisited[i];
        }
    }

    //Array
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(src) == '[object Array]') {
        //[].slice() by itself would soft clone
        var ret = src.slice();

        //add it to the visited array
        _visited.push(src);
        _copiesVisited.push(ret);

        var i = ret.length;
        while (i--) {
            ret[i] = deepCopy(ret[i], _visited, _copiesVisited);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    //If we've reached here, we have a regular object

    //make sure the returned object has the same prototype as the original
    var proto = (Object.getPrototypeOf ? Object.getPrototypeOf(src): src.__proto__);
    if (!proto) {
        proto = src.constructor.prototype; //this line would probably only be reached by very old browsers 
    }
    var dest = object_create(proto);

    //add this object to the visited array
    _visited.push(src);
    _copiesVisited.push(dest);

    for (var key in src) {
        //Note: this does NOT preserve ES5 property attributes like 'writable', 'enumerable', etc.
        //For an example of how this could be modified to do so, see the singleMixin() function
        dest[key] = deepCopy(src[key], _visited, _copiesVisited);
    }
    return dest;
}

//If Object.create isn't already defined, we just do the simple shim,
//without the second argument, since that's all we need here
var object_create = Object.create;
if (typeof object_create !== 'function') {
    object_create = function(o) {
        function F() {}
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
}
```

Answer (score 33):

The following creates two instances of the same object. I found it and am using it currently. It's simple and easy to use.

```
var objToCreate = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cloneThis));
```

Answer (score 31):

Crockford suggests (and I prefer) using this function:

```
function object(o) {
    function F() {}
    F.prototype = o;
    return new F();
}

var newObject = object(oldObject);
```

It's terse, works as expected and you don't need a library.

---

**EDIT:**

This is a polyfill for `Object.create`, so you also can use this.

```
var newObject = Object.create(oldObject);
```

**NOTE:**  If you use some of this, you may have problems with some iteration who use `hasOwnProperty`. Because, `create` create new empty object who inherits `oldObject`. But it is still useful and practical for cloning objects.

For exemple if  `oldObject.a = 5;`

```
newObject.a; // is 5
```

but:

```
oldObject.hasOwnProperty(a); // is true
newObject.hasOwnProperty(a); // is false
```

Answer (score 25):

```
function clone(obj)
 { var clone = {};
   clone.prototype = obj.prototype;
   for (property in obj) clone[property] = obj[property];
   return clone;
 }
```

Answer (score 23):

Lodash has a nice [_.cloneDeep(value)](http://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep) method:

```
var objects = [{ 'a': 1 }, { 'b': 2 }];

var deep = _.cloneDeep(objects);
console.log(deep[0] === objects[0]);
// => false
```

Answer (score 22):

Shallow copy one-liner ([ECMAScript 5th edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#5th_Edition)):

```
var origin = { foo : {} };
var copy = Object.keys(origin).reduce(function(c,k){c[k]=origin[k];return c;},{});

console.log(origin, copy);
console.log(origin == copy); // false
console.log(origin.foo == copy.foo); // true
```

And shallow copy one-liner ([ECMAScript 6th edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015), 2015):

```
var origin = { foo : {} };
var copy = Object.assign({}, origin);

console.log(origin, copy);
console.log(origin == copy); // false
console.log(origin.foo == copy.foo); // true
```

Comment: This is a **shallow copy** and a **deep clone** like the question asked for. This will not work for nested objects.

Answer (score 21):

There seems to be no ideal deep clone operator yet for array-like objects.  As the code below illustrates, John Resig's jQuery cloner turns arrays with non-numeric properties into objects that are not arrays, and RegDwight's JSON cloner drops the non-numeric properties. The following tests illustrate these points on multiple browsers:

```
function jQueryClone(obj) {
   return jQuery.extend(true, {}, obj)
}

function JSONClone(obj) {
   return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
}

var arrayLikeObj = [[1, "a", "b"], [2, "b", "a"]];
arrayLikeObj.names = ["m", "n", "o"];
var JSONCopy = JSONClone(arrayLikeObj);
var jQueryCopy = jQueryClone(arrayLikeObj);

alert("Is arrayLikeObj an array instance?" + (arrayLikeObj instanceof Array) +
      "\nIs the jQueryClone an array instance? " + (jQueryCopy instanceof Array) +
      "\nWhat are the arrayLikeObj names? " + arrayLikeObj.names +
      "\nAnd what are the JSONClone names? " + JSONCopy.names)
```

Answer (score 19):

Just because I didn't see [AngularJS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS) mentioned and thought that people might want to know...

[`angular.copy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) also provides a method of deep copying objects and arrays.

Comment: or it might be used the same way as jQiery extend: `angular.extend({},obj);`

Comment: @Galvani: It should be noted that `jQuery.extend` and `angular.extend` are both shallow copies. `angular.copy` is a deep copy.

Answer (score 18):

I have two good answers depending on whether your objective is to clone a "plain old JavaScript object" or not.

Let's also assume that your intention is to create a complete clone with no prototype references back to the source object. If you're not interested in a complete clone, then you can use many of the Object.clone() routines provided in some of the other answers (Crockford's pattern).

For plain old JavaScript objects, a tried and true good way to clone an object in modern runtimes is quite simply:

```
var clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Note that the source object must be a pure JSON object. This is to say, all of its nested properties must be scalars (like boolean, string, array, object, etc). Any functions or special objects like RegExp or Date will not be cloned.

Is it efficient? Heck yes. We've tried all kinds of cloning methods and this works best. I'm sure some ninja could conjure up a faster method. But I suspect we're talking about marginal gains.

This approach is just simple and easy to implement. Wrap it into a convenience function and if you really need to squeeze out some gain, go for at a later time.

Now, for non-plain JavaScript objects, there isn't a really simple answer.  In fact, there can't be because of the dynamic nature of JavaScript functions and inner object state. Deep cloning a JSON structure with functions inside requires you recreate those functions and their inner context. And JavaScript simply doesn't have a standardized way of doing that.

The correct way to do this, once again, is via a convenience method that you declare and reuse within your code. The convenience method can be endowed with some understanding of your own objects so you can make sure to properly recreate the graph within the new object.

We're written our own, but the best general approach I've seen is covered here:

http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-clone

This is the right idea. The author (David Walsh) has commented out the cloning of generalized functions. This is something you might choose to do, depending on your use case.

The main idea is that you need to special handle the instantiation of your functions (or prototypal classes, so to speak) on a per-type basis. Here, he's provided a few examples for RegExp and Date.

Not only is this code brief, but it's also very readable. It's pretty easy to extend.

Is this efficient? Heck yes. Given that the goal is to produce a true deep-copy clone, then you're going to have to walk the members of the source object graph. With this approach, you can tweak exactly which child members to treat and how to manually handle custom types.

So there you go. Two approaches. Both are efficient in my view.

Answer (score 18):

Only when you can use [ECMAScript 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) or [transpilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler).

Features:

- Won't trigger getter/setter while copying.
- Preserves getter/setter.
- Preserves prototype informations.
- Works with both **object-literal** and **functional** [OO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) writing styles.

Code:

```
function clone(target, source){

    for(let key in source){

        // Use getOwnPropertyDescriptor instead of source[key] to prevent from trigering setter/getter.
        let descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, key);
        if(descriptor.value instanceof String){
            target[key] = new String(descriptor.value);
        }
        else if(descriptor.value instanceof Array){
            target[key] = clone([], descriptor.value);
        }
        else if(descriptor.value instanceof Object){
            let prototype = Reflect.getPrototypeOf(descriptor.value);
            let cloneObject = clone({}, descriptor.value);
            Reflect.setPrototypeOf(cloneObject, prototype);
            target[key] = cloneObject;
        }
        else {
            Object.defineProperty(target, key, descriptor);
        }
    }
    let prototype = Reflect.getPrototypeOf(source);
    Reflect.setPrototypeOf(target, prototype);
    return target;
}
```

Comment: Problematic for data types like `Date`

Comment: This will create a reference to the same object instance (_not_ deep-copying it) if used with objects that have a `null` prototype, since `Object.create(null) instanceof Object` is false.

Answer (score 18):

I am late to answer this question, but I have an another way of cloning the object:

```
function cloneObject(obj) {
    if (obj === null || typeof(obj) !== 'object')
        return obj;
    var temp = obj.constructor(); // changed
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
            obj['isActiveClone'] = null;
            temp[key] = cloneObject(obj[key]);
            delete obj['isActiveClone'];
        }
    }
    return temp;
}

var b = cloneObject({"a":1,"b":2});   // calling
```

which is much better and faster then:

```
var a = {"a":1,"b":2};
var b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));
```

and

```
var a = {"a":1,"b":2};

// Deep copy
var newObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, a);
```

I have bench-marked the code and you can test the results [here](http://jsben.ch/vyEky):

and sharing the results:
[image]
References: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Comment: its funny but when I run your tests it actually shoed me that method 1 is the slowest one

Comment: same as me, block 1 is the lowest!

Comment: Only solution that worked for me! Had to deep clone an object that contained other objects with function properties. Perfect.

Comment: Why do you set `obj['isActiveClone'] = null` and then delete it?
And why don't you call `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)`?

Answer (score 16):

This isn't generally the most efficient solution, but it does what I need. Simple test cases below...

```
function clone(obj, clones) {
    // Makes a deep copy of 'obj'. Handles cyclic structures by
    // tracking cloned obj's in the 'clones' parameter. Functions 
    // are included, but not cloned. Functions members are cloned.
    var new_obj,
        already_cloned,
        t = typeof obj,
        i = 0,
        l,
        pair; 

    clones = clones || [];

    if (obj === null) {
        return obj;
    }

    if (t === "object" || t === "function") {

        // check to see if we've already cloned obj
        for (i = 0, l = clones.length; i < l; i++) {
            pair = clones[i];
            if (pair[0] === obj) {
                already_cloned = pair[1];
                break;
            }
        }

        if (already_cloned) {
            return already_cloned; 
        } else {
            if (t === "object") { // create new object
                new_obj = new obj.constructor();
            } else { // Just use functions as is
                new_obj = obj;
            }

            clones.push([obj, new_obj]); // keep track of objects we've cloned

            for (key in obj) { // clone object members
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    new_obj[key] = clone(obj[key], clones);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return new_obj || obj;
}
```

Cyclic array test...

```
a = []
a.push("b", "c", a)
aa = clone(a)
aa === a //=> false
aa[2] === a //=> false
aa[2] === a[2] //=> false
aa[2] === aa //=> true
```

Function test...

```
f = new Function
f.a = a
ff = clone(f)
ff === f //=> true
ff.a === a //=> false
```

Answer (score 16):

For the people who want to use the `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` version, but without losing the Date objects, you can use the [second argument of `parse` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter) to convert the strings back to Date:

```js
function clone(obj) {
  var regExp = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}Z$/;
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj), function(k, v) {
    if (typeof v === 'string' && regExp.test(v))
      return new Date(v)
    return v;
  })
}

// usage:
var original = {
 a: [1, null, undefined, 0, {a:null}, new Date()],
 b: {
   c(){ return 0 }
 }
}

var cloned = clone(original)

console.log(cloned)
```

Comment: Not quite a 100% clone

Answer (score 14):

```
// obj target object, vals source object
var setVals = function (obj, vals) {
    if (obj && vals) {
        for (var x in vals) {
            if (vals.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
                if (obj[x] && typeof vals[x] === 'object') {
                    obj[x] = setVals(obj[x], vals[x]);
                } else {
                    obj[x] = vals[x];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
};
```

Answer (score 14):

I disagree with the answer with the greatest votes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5344074/1110941). A **Recursive Deep Clone** is **much faster** than the *JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))* approach mentioned.

- **Jsperf** ranks it number one here: https://jsperf.com/deep-copy-vs-json-stringify-json-parse/5
- **Jsben** from the answer above updated to show that a recursive deep clone beats all the others mentioned: http://jsben.ch/13YKQ

And here's the function for quick reference:

```
function cloneDeep (o) {
  let newO
  let i

  if (typeof o !== 'object') return o

  if (!o) return o

  if (Object.prototype.toString.apply(o) === '[object Array]') {
    newO = []
    for (i = 0; i < o.length; i += 1) {
      newO[i] = cloneDeep(o[i])
    }
    return newO
  }

  newO = {}
  for (i in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      newO[i] = cloneDeep(o[i])
    }
  }
  return newO
}
```

Comment: I liked this approach but it doesn't handle dates properly; consider adding something like `if(o instanceof Date) return new Date(o.valueOf());` after checking for null
`

Comment: Crashes on circular references.

Comment: In latest stable Firefox, this is way longer than the other strategies at that Jsben.ch link, by an order of magnitude or more.  It beats the others in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a comprehensive clone() method that can clone any JavaScript object. It handles almost all the cases:

```
function clone(src, deep) {

    var toString = Object.prototype.toString;
    if (!src && typeof src != "object") {
        // Any non-object (Boolean, String, Number), null, undefined, NaN
        return src;
    }

    // Honor native/custom clone methods
    if (src.clone && toString.call(src.clone) == "[object Function]") {
        return src.clone(deep);
    }

    // DOM elements
    if (src.nodeType && toString.call(src.cloneNode) == "[object Function]") {
        return src.cloneNode(deep);
    }

    // Date
    if (toString.call(src) == "[object Date]") {
        return new Date(src.getTime());
    }

    // RegExp
    if (toString.call(src) == "[object RegExp]") {
        return new RegExp(src);
    }

    // Function
    if (toString.call(src) == "[object Function]") {

        //Wrap in another method to make sure == is not true;
        //Note: Huge performance issue due to closures, comment this :)
        return (function(){
            src.apply(this, arguments);
        });
    }

    var ret, index;
    //Array
    if (toString.call(src) == "[object Array]") {
        //[].slice(0) would soft clone
        ret = src.slice();
        if (deep) {
            index = ret.length;
            while (index--) {
                ret[index] = clone(ret[index], true);
            }
        }
    }
    //Object
    else {
        ret = src.constructor ? new src.constructor() : {};
        for (var prop in src) {
            ret[prop] = deep
                ? clone(src[prop], true)
                : src[prop];
        }
    }
    return ret;
};
```

Comment: It converts primitives into wrapper objects, not a good solution in most cases.

Comment: @DanubianSailor - I don't think it does...it seems to return primitives right away from the start, and doesn't seem to be doing anything to them that would turn them into wrapper objects as they are returned.

Answer (score 12):

### AngularJS

Well if you're using angular you could do this too

```
var newObject = angular.copy(oldObject);
```

Answer (score 12):

> In JavaScript, you can write your `deepCopy` method like

```
function deepCopy(src) {
  let target = Array.isArray(src) ? [] : {};
  for (let prop in src) {
    let value = src[prop];
    if(value && typeof value === 'object') {
      target[prop] = deepCopy(value);
  } else {
      target[prop] = value;
  }
 }
    return target;
}
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to global Object pollution. It should not copy `prop` if `(prop === 'constuctor' && typeof src[prop] === 'function')` or if `(prop === '__proto__')`

Answer (score 10):

In my experience, a recursive version vastly outperforms `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`. Here is a modernized recursive deep object copy function which can fit on a single line:

```
function deepCopy(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((v, d) => Object.assign(v, {
    [d]: (obj[d].constructor === Object) ? deepCopy(obj[d]) : obj[d]
  }), {});
}
```

This is performing around [40 times faster](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/ShowResult/25487) than the `JSON.parse...` method.

Comment: Pseudocode would be: for each key, assign its value to the same key in a new object (shallow copy). However if the value is of type `Object` (can't shallow copy), the function recursively calls itself with the value as an argument.

Comment: Too bad it doesn't work right when the value is an array.
But, shouldn't be too difficult to modify to get it to work for that case.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined

Comment: Doesn't work for null as it tries to access `null.constructor`, doesn't work for arrays as it turns them into objects.

Answer (score 8):

I use the npm clone library.  Apparently it also works in the browser.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/clone

```
let a = clone(b)
```

Answer (score 7):

As recursion is just too expensive for JavaScript, and most answers I have found are using recursion, while JSON approach will skip the non-JSON-convertible parts (Function, etc.). So I did a little research and found this trampoline technique to avoid it. Here's the code:

```
/*
 * Trampoline to avoid recursion in JavaScript, see:
 *     https://www.integralist.co.uk/posts/functional-recursive-javascript-programming/
 */
function trampoline() {
    var func = arguments[0];
    var args = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        args[i - 1] = arguments[i];
    }

    var currentBatch = func.apply(this, args);
    var nextBatch = [];

    while (currentBatch && currentBatch.length > 0) {
        currentBatch.forEach(function(eachFunc) {
            var ret = eachFunc();
            if (ret && ret.length > 0) {
                nextBatch = nextBatch.concat(ret);
            }
        });

        currentBatch = nextBatch;
        nextBatch = [];
    }
};

/*
 *  Deep clone an object using the trampoline technique.
 *
 *  @param target {Object} Object to clone
 *  @return {Object} Cloned object.
 */
function clone(target) {
    if (typeof target !== 'object') {
        return target;
    }
    if (target == null || Object.keys(target).length == 0) {
        return target;
    }

    function _clone(b, a) {
        var nextBatch = [];
        for (var key in b) {
            if (typeof b[key] === 'object' && b[key] !== null) {
                if (b[key] instanceof Array) {
                    a[key] = [];
                }
                else {
                    a[key] = {};
                }
                nextBatch.push(_clone.bind(null, b[key], a[key]));
            }
            else {
                a[key] = b[key];
            }
        }
        return nextBatch;
    };

    var ret = target instanceof Array ? [] : {};
    (trampoline.bind(null, _clone))(target, ret);
    return ret;
};
```

Comment: Tail call recursion is actually very efficient in most implementations of JavaScript, and is required to be optimized in ES6.

Comment: Hi I did a little test back then, and when the target object becomes complex, the call stack would easily overflow, though I didn't take any notes, hopefully in es6 this will be a big op.

Comment: Stack would easily overflow, probably because of the circular reference.

Answer (score 6):

For future reference, the current draft of [ECMAScript 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_-_ECMAScript_2015) introduces [Object.assign](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object.assign) as a way of cloning objects. Example code would be:

```
var obj1 = { a: true, b: 1 };
var obj2 = Object.assign(obj1);
console.log(obj2); // { a: true, b: 1 }
```

At the time of writing [support is limited to Firefox 34 in browsers](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#Object.assign) so it’s not usable in production code just yet (unless you’re writing a Firefox extension of course).

Comment: You probably meant `obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj1)`. Your current code is equivalent to `obj2 = obj1`.

Comment: This is a shallow-clone. `const o1 = { a: { deep: 123 } }; const o2 = Object.assign({}, o1); o2.a.deep = 456;` now `o1.a.deep === 456` too.

Comment: `Object.assign()` is not for cloning nested objects.

Comment: Wow, another useless answer. Taken from MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign : `Warning for Deep Clone -
 For deep cloning, we need to use other alternatives because Object.assign() copies property values. If the source value is a reference to an object, it only copies that reference value.`

Answer (score 6):

Single-line ECMAScript 6 solution (special object types like Date/Regex not handled):

```js
const clone = (o) =>
  typeof o === 'object' && o !== null ?      // only clone objects
  (Array.isArray(o) ?                        // if cloning an array
    o.map(e => clone(e)) :                   // clone each of its elements
    Object.keys(o).reduce(                   // otherwise reduce every key in the object
      (r, k) => (r[k] = clone(o[k]), r), {}  // and save its cloned value into a new object
    )
  ) :
  o;                                         // return non-objects as is

var x = {
  nested: {
    name: 'test'
  }
};

var y = clone(x);

console.log(x.nested !== y.nested);
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation alongside a code chunk so that others with a similar question can easily understand what is happening. As it stands now, this question is in a low quality posts review queue.

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 6):

Lodash has a function that handles that for you like so.

```
var foo = {a: 'a', b: {c:'d', e: {f: 'g'}}};

var bar = _.cloneDeep(foo);
// bar = {a: 'a', b: {c:'d', e: {f: 'g'}}}
```

Read the docs [here](https://lodash.com/docs/#cloneDeep).

Comment: I ended up using this, since the JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)) does not keep the original object prototype

Comment: This is my goto answer. Except that I use Lodash's merge, keeps the syntax somewhat consistent for deep and shallow copying.
`//Deep copy:
_.merge({},foo)
//Shallow copy:
Object.Assign({}, foo)`

Answer (score 6):

ES 2017 example:

```
let objectToCopy = someObj;
let copyOfObject = {};
Object.defineProperties(copyOfObject, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(objectToCopy));
// copyOfObject will now be the same as objectToCopy
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried your approach, but unfortunately, it does not work. Because it could be some kind of mistake on my side, I ask you for check my [example in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x8k9avf2/9/)  and if it will be some mistake on my side, I'll vote up for your answer.

Comment: When I run your fiddle, I get `{ foo: 1, bar: { fooBar: 22, fooBaz: 33, fooFoo:  11 }, baz: 3}` and `{ foo: 1, bar: { fooBar: 22, fooBaz: 44, fooFoo:  11 }, baz: 4}`.  Is that not what you expect to happen?

Comment: what you pasted is what I expected. I don't understand why, but I see `fooBaz: 44` for both `testObj2` and `testObj3` in console... ([screenshot](http://prntscr.com/jt5tj0))

Comment: This is not a deep copy but a shallow copy. @GurebuBokofu

Answer (score 5):

This is the fastest method I have created that doesn't use the prototype, so it will maintain hasOwnProperty in the new object.

The solution is to iterate the top level properties of the original object, make two copies, delete each property from the original and then reset the original object and return the new copy. It only has to iterate as many times as top level properties. This saves all the `if` conditions to check if each property is a function, object, string, etc., and doesn't have to iterate each descendant property.

The only drawback is that the original object must be supplied with its original created namespace, in order to reset it.

```
copyDeleteAndReset:function(namespace,strObjName){
    var obj = namespace[strObjName],
    objNew = {},objOrig = {};
    for(i in obj){
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i)){
            objNew[i] = objOrig[i] = obj[i];
            delete obj[i];
        }
    }
    namespace[strObjName] = objOrig;
    return objNew;
}

var namespace = {};
namespace.objOrig = {
    '0':{
        innerObj:{a:0,b:1,c:2}
    }
}

var objNew = copyDeleteAndReset(namespace,'objOrig');
objNew['0'] = 'NEW VALUE';

console.log(objNew['0']) === 'NEW VALUE';
console.log(namespace.objOrig['0']) === innerObj:{a:0,b:1,c:2};
```

Comment: This is a shallow copy and doesn't work for arrays. It also declares `i` in the global scope.

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of answers, but none of them gave the desired effect I needed.  I wanted to utilize the power of jQuery's deep copy... However, when it runs into an array, it simply copies the reference to the array and deep copies the items in it.  To get around this, I made a nice little recursive function that will create a new array automatically.

(It even checks for kendo.data.ObservableArray if you want it to!  Though, make sure you make sure you call kendo.observable(newItem) if you want the Arrays to be observable again.)

So, to fully copy an existing item, you just do this:

```
var newItem = jQuery.extend(true, {}, oldItem);
createNewArrays(newItem);


function createNewArrays(obj) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if ((kendo != null && obj[prop] instanceof kendo.data.ObservableArray) || obj[prop] instanceof Array) {
            var copy = [];
            $.each(obj[prop], function (i, item) {
                var newChild = $.extend(true, {}, item);
                createNewArrays(newChild);
                copy.push(newChild);
            });
            obj[prop] = copy;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I usually use `var newObj = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify(oldObje) );` but, here's a more proper way:

```
var o = {};

var oo = Object.create(o);

(o === oo); // => false
```

Watch legacy browsers!

Comment: The second way needs a Prototype, I prefer the first way, even if it's not the best one on performance due to you can use with a lot of browsers and with Node JS.

Comment: That's cool and all but suppose o has a property a.  Now does oo.hasOwnProperty('a')?

Comment: No -- o is essentially added as a prototype of oo. This is likely not going to be the desired behavior, which is why 99.9% of the serialize() methods I write use the JSON approach mentioned above. I basically always use JSON, and there're other caveats exposed when using Object.create.

Comment: No, watch this code! `Object.create` doesn't necessary create a copy of an object instead it uses the older object as a prototype for the clone

Answer (score 5):

There are so many ways to achieve this, but if you want to do this without any library, you can use the following:

```
const cloneObject = (oldObject) => {
  let newObject = oldObject;
  if (oldObject && typeof oldObject === 'object') {
    if(Array.isArray(oldObject)) {
      newObject = [];
    } else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(oldObject) === '[object Date]' && !isNaN(oldObject)) {
      newObject = new Date(oldObject.getTime());
    } else {
      newObject = {};
      for (let i in oldObject) {
        newObject[i] = cloneObject(oldObject[i]);
      }
    }

  }
  return newObject;
}
```

Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 5):

`Object.assign({},sourceObj)` only clones the object if their property is not having reference type key.
ex

```
obj={a:"lol",b:["yes","no","maybe"]}
clonedObj = Object.assign({},obj);

clonedObj.b.push("skip")// changes will reflected to the actual obj as well because of its reference type.
obj.b //will also console => yes,no,maybe,skip
```

So for the deep cloning is not possible to achieve in this way.

The best solution that works is

```
var obj = Json.stringify(yourSourceObj)
var cloned = Json.parse(obj);
```

Comment: Far from "best". maybe for simple objects.

Comment: This answer is not correct - `Object.assign()` is a shallow copy, and `Json` is not the right way to use the `JSON` utilities.

Answer (score 4):

This is my version of object cloner. This is a stand-alone version of the jQuery method, with only few tweaks and adjustments. Check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eyYJB/). I've used a lot of jQuery until the day I realized that I'd use only this function most of the time x_x.

The usage is the same as described into the jQuery API:

- Non-deep clone: `extend(object_dest, object_source);`
- Deep clone: `extend(true, object_dest, object_source);`

One extra function is used to define if object is proper to be cloned.

```
/**
 * This is a quasi clone of jQuery's extend() function.
 * by Romain WEEGER for wJs library - www.wexample.com
 * @returns {*|{}}
 */
function extend() {
    // Make a copy of arguments to avoid JavaScript inspector hints.
    var to_add, name, copy_is_array, clone,

    // The target object who receive parameters
    // form other objects.
    target = arguments[0] || {},

    // Index of first argument to mix to target.
    i = 1,

    // Mix target with all function arguments.
    length = arguments.length,

    // Define if we merge object recursively.
    deep = false;

    // Handle a deep copy situation.
    if (typeof target === 'boolean') {
        deep = target;

        // Skip the boolean and the target.
        target = arguments[ i ] || {};

        // Use next object as first added.
        i++;
    }

    // Handle case when target is a string or something (possible in deep copy)
    if (typeof target !== 'object' && typeof target !== 'function') {
        target = {};
    }

    // Loop trough arguments.
    for (false; i < length; i += 1) {

        // Only deal with non-null/undefined values
        if ((to_add = arguments[ i ]) !== null) {

            // Extend the base object.
            for (name in to_add) {

                // We do not wrap for loop into hasOwnProperty,
                // to access to all values of object.
                // Prevent never-ending loop.
                if (target === to_add[name]) {
                    continue;
                }

                // Recurse if we're merging plain objects or arrays.
                if (deep && to_add[name] && (is_plain_object(to_add[name]) || (copy_is_array = Array.isArray(to_add[name])))) {
                    if (copy_is_array) {
                        copy_is_array = false;
                        clone = target[name] && Array.isArray(target[name]) ? target[name] : [];
                    }
                    else {
                        clone = target[name] && is_plain_object(target[name]) ? target[name] : {};
                    }

                    // Never move original objects, clone them.
                    target[name] = extend(deep, clone, to_add[name]);
                }

                // Don't bring in undefined values.
                else if (to_add[name] !== undefined) {
                    target[name] = to_add[name];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return target;
}

/**
 * Check to see if an object is a plain object
 * (created using "{}" or "new Object").
 * Forked from jQuery.
 * @param obj
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function is_plain_object(obj) {
    // Not plain objects:
    // - Any object or value whose internal [[Class]] property is not "[object Object]"
    // - DOM nodes
    // - window
    if (obj === null || typeof obj !== "object" || obj.nodeType || (obj !== null && obj === obj.window)) {
        return false;
    }
    // Support: Firefox <20
    // The try/catch suppresses exceptions thrown when attempting to access
    // the "constructor" property of certain host objects, i.e. |window.location|
    // https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=814622
    try {
        if (obj.constructor && !this.hasOwnProperty.call(obj.constructor.prototype, "isPrototypeOf")) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        return false;
    }

    // If the function hasn't returned already, we're confident that
    // |obj| is a plain object, created by {} or constructed with new Object
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You may want to add `|| typeof target[name] !== "undefined"` when testing `if (target === to_add[name]) { continue; }` to not overwrite the existing members of `target`. For example `var a={hello:"world", foo:"bar"}; var b={hello:"you"}; extend(b, a);` we expect to find `b => {hello:"you", foo:"bar"}`, but with your code we find: `b => {hello:"world", foo:"bar"}`

Comment: In my case I expected indeed to overwrite existing members, so the current behaviour was the wright one for this usage. But thank you to add this helpful suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my way of deep cloning a object with `ES2015` default value and spread operator

```
 const makeDeepCopy = (obj, copy = {}) => {
  for (let item in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[item] === 'object') {
      makeDeepCopy(obj[item], copy)
    }
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
      copy = {
        ...obj
      }
    }
  }
  return copy
}
```

```js
const testObj = {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "userId": {
      "type": "string",
      "chance": "guid"
    },
    "emailAddr": {
      "type": "string",
      "chance": {
        "email": {
          "domain": "fake.com"
        }
      },
      "pattern": ".+@fake.com"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "userId",
    "emailAddr"
  ]
}

const makeDeepCopy = (obj, copy = {}) => {
  for (let item in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[item] === 'object') {
      makeDeepCopy(obj[item], copy)
    }
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
      copy = {
        ...obj
      }
    }
  }
  return copy
}

console.log(makeDeepCopy(testObj))
```

Comment: Tour `test` object is **too naive**. it must have some `undefined`, functions, dates and `null` and not just a bunch of strings

Comment: Doesn't work for fields where the value is null, nor does it work for fields where the value is an array.

Answer (score 4):

Looking through this long list of answers nearly all the solutions have been covered except one that I am aware of. This is the list of VANILLA JS ways of deep cloning an object.

1. JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( obj ) );
2. Through history.state with pushState or replaceState
3. Web Notifications API but this has the downside of asking the user for permissions.
4. Doing your own recursive loop through the object to copy each level.
5. The answer I didn't see -> Using ServiceWorkers. The messages (objects) passed back and forth between the page and the ServiceWorker script will be deep clones of any object.

Comment: All these have already been converted either in the answers or the comments. I would vote this up if you gave unique code examples for each one though.

Answer (score 4):

Hope this helps.

```
function deepClone(obj) {
    /*
     * Duplicates an object 
     */

    var ret = null;
    if (obj !== Object(obj)) { // primitive types
        return obj;
    }
    if (obj instanceof String || obj instanceof Number || obj instanceof Boolean) { // string objecs
        ret = obj; // for ex: obj = new String("Spidergap")
    } else if (obj instanceof Date) { // date
        ret = new obj.constructor();
    } else
        ret = Object.create(obj.constructor.prototype);

    var prop = null;
    var allProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj); //gets non enumerables also


    var props = {};
    for (var i in allProps) {
        prop = allProps[i];
        props[prop] = false;
    }

    for (i in obj) {
        props[i] = i;
    }

    //now props contain both enums and non enums 
    var propDescriptor = null;
    var newPropVal = null; // value of the property in new object
    for (i in props) {
        prop = obj[i];
        propDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, i);

        if (Array.isArray(prop)) { //not backward compatible
            prop = prop.slice(); // to copy the array
        } else
        if (prop instanceof Date == true) {
            prop = new prop.constructor();
        } else
        if (prop instanceof Object == true) {
            if (prop instanceof Function == true) { // function
                if (!Function.prototype.clone) {
                    Function.prototype.clone = function() {
                        var that = this;
                        var temp = function tmp() {
                            return that.apply(this, arguments);
                        };
                        for (var ky in this) {
                            temp[ky] = this[ky];
                        }
                        return temp;
                    }
                }
                prop = prop.clone();

            } else // normal object 
            {
                prop = deepClone(prop);
            }

        }

        newPropVal = {
            value: prop
        };
        if (propDescriptor) {
            /*
             * If property descriptors are there, they must be copied
             */
            newPropVal.enumerable = propDescriptor.enumerable;
            newPropVal.writable = propDescriptor.writable;

        }
        if (!ret.hasOwnProperty(i)) // when String or other predefined objects
            Object.defineProperty(ret, i, newPropVal); // non enumerable

    }
    return ret;
}
```

https://github.com/jinujd/Javascript-Deep-Clone

Answer (score 4):

My scenario was a bit different. I had an object with nested objects as well as functions. Therefore, `Object.assign()` and `JSON.stringify()` were not solutions to my problem. Using third-party libraries was not an option for me neither.

Hence, I decided to make a simple function to use built-in methods to copy an object with its literal properties, its nested objects, and functions.

```
let deepCopy = (target, source) => {
    Object.assign(target, source);
    // check if there's any nested objects
    Object.keys(source).forEach((prop) => {
        /**
          * assign function copies functions and
          * literals (int, strings, etc...)
          * except for objects and arrays, so:
          */
        if (typeof(source[prop]) === 'object') {
            // check if the item is, in fact, an array
            if (Array.isArray(source[prop])) {
                // clear the copied referenece of nested array
                target[prop] = Array();
                // iterate array's item and copy over
                source[prop].forEach((item, index) => {
                    // array's items could be objects too!
                    if (typeof(item) === 'object') {
                        // clear the copied referenece of nested objects
                        target[prop][index] = Object();
                        // and re do the process for nested objects
                        deepCopy(target[prop][index], item);
                    } else {
                        target[prop].push(item);
                    }
                });
            // otherwise, treat it as an object
            } else {
                // clear the copied referenece of nested objects
                target[prop] = Object();
                // and re do the process for nested objects
                deepCopy(target[prop], source[prop]);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Here's a test code:

```
let a = {
    name: 'Human', 
    func: () => {
        console.log('Hi!');
    }, 
    prop: {
        age: 21, 
        info: {
            hasShirt: true, 
            hasHat: false
        }
    },
    mark: [89, 92, { exam: [1, 2, 3] }]
};

let b = Object();

deepCopy(b, a);

a.name = 'Alien';
a.func = () => { console.log('Wassup!'); };
a.prop.age = 1024;
a.prop.info.hasShirt = false;
a.mark[0] = 87;
a.mark[1] = 91;
a.mark[2].exam = [4, 5, 6];

console.log(a); // updated props
console.log(b);
```

For efficiency-related concerns, I believe this is the simplest and most efficient solution to the problem I had. I would appreciate any comments on this algorithm that could make it more efficient.

Comment: This code replaces `null` inside objects with `{}`, as `typeof null === "object"`

Answer (score 3):

I think that this is the best solution  if you want to generalize your object cloning algorithm.
It can be used with or without jQuery, although I recommend leaving jQuery's extend method out if you want you the cloned object to have the same "class" as the original one.

```
function clone(obj){
    if(typeof(obj) == 'function')//it's a simple function
        return obj;
    //of it's not an object (but could be an array...even if in javascript arrays are objects)
    if(typeof(obj) !=  'object' || obj.constructor.toString().indexOf('Array')!=-1)
        if(JSON != undefined)//if we have the JSON obj
            try{
                return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
            }catch(err){
                return JSON.parse('"'+JSON.stringify(obj)+'"');
            }
        else
            try{
                return eval(uneval(obj));
            }catch(err){
                return eval('"'+uneval(obj)+'"');
            }
    // I used to rely on jQuery for this, but the "extend" function returns
    //an object similar to the one cloned,
    //but that was not an instance (instanceof) of the cloned class
    /*
    if(jQuery != undefined)//if we use the jQuery plugin
        return jQuery.extend(true,{},obj);
    else//we recursivley clone the object
    */
    return (function _clone(obj){
        if(obj == null || typeof(obj) != 'object')
            return obj;
        function temp () {};
        temp.prototype = obj;
        var F = new temp;
        for(var key in obj)
            F[key] = clone(obj[key]);
        return F;
    })(obj);            
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Object.create()` to get the `prototype` and support for `instanceof`, and use a `for()` loop to get enumerable keys:

```
function cloneObject(source) {
    var key,value;
    var clone = Object.create(source);

    for (key in source) {
        if (source.hasOwnProperty(key) === true) {
            value = source[key];

            if (value!==null && typeof value==="object") {
                clone[key] = cloneObject(value);
            } else {
                clone[key] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    return clone;
}
```

Comment: Great answer! I think this is the one of the only methods to keep setters and getter intact. This solved my problem. Thanks! (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207028/javascript-setter-and-getter-of-object-lost-after-angular-copy)

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use clone = `Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(source))`, instead of inheriting properties which you also overwrite?

Comment: Interesting. Though, using `getPrototypeOf` on an `Array` turns its indexes into keys of a new `Object`.

Comment: Doesn't work for arrays, as it uses `Object.create()` to try and create arrays.

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, one can use this code

ES6:

```
_clone: function(obj){
    let newObj = {};
    for(let i in obj){
        if(typeof(obj[i]) === 'object' && Object.keys(obj[i]).length){
            newObj[i] = clone(obj[i]);
        } else{
            newObj[i] = obj[i];
        }
    }
    return Object.assign({},newObj);
}
```

ES5:

```
function clone(obj){
let newObj = {};
for(let i in obj){
    if(typeof(obj[i]) === 'object' && Object.keys(obj[i]).length){
        newObj[i] = clone(obj[i]);
    } else{
        newObj[i] = obj[i];
    }
}
return Object.assign({},newObj);
```

}

E.g

```
var obj ={a:{b:1,c:3},d:4,e:{f:6}}
var xc = clone(obj);
console.log(obj); //{a:{b:1,c:3},d:4,e:{f:6}}
console.log(xc); //{a:{b:1,c:3},d:4,e:{f:6}}

xc.a.b = 90;
console.log(obj); //{a:{b:1,c:3},d:4,e:{f:6}}
console.log(xc); //{a:{b:90,c:3},d:4,e:{f:6}}
```

Comment: this does not handle arrays, that are, indeed, objects as well.

Comment: Doesn't work for arrays or null, as the typeof check is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

```js
class Handler {
  static deepCopy (obj) {
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]') {
      const result = [];
      
      for (let i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++) {
        result[i] = Handler.deepCopy(obj[i]);
      }
      return result;
    } else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Object]') {
      const result = {};
      for (let prop in obj) {
        result[prop] = Handler.deepCopy(obj[prop]);
      }
      return result;
    }
    return obj;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Without touching the prototypical inheritance you may deep lone objects and arrays as follows;

```js
function objectClone(o){
  var ot = Array.isArray(o);
  return o !== null && typeof o === "object" ? Object.keys(o)
                                                     .reduce((r,k) => o[k] !== null && typeof o[k] === "object" ? (r[k] = objectClone(o[k]),r)
                                                                                                                : (r[k] = o[k],r), ot ? [] : {})
                                             : o;
}
var obj = {a: 1, b: {c: 2, d: {e: 3, f: {g: 4, h: null}}}},
    arr = [1,2,[3,4,[5,6,[7]]]],
    nil = null,
  clobj = objectClone(obj),
  clarr = objectClone(arr),
  clnil = objectClone(nil);
console.log(clobj, obj === clobj);
console.log(clarr, arr === clarr);
console.log(clnil, nil === clnil);
clarr[2][2][2] = "seven";
console.log(arr, clarr);
```

Answer (score 3):

What about asynchronous object cloning done by a `Promise`?

```
async function clone(thingy /**/)
{
    if(thingy instanceof Promise)
    {
        throw Error("This function cannot clone Promises.");
    }
    return thingy;
}
```

Comment: Hold on, 5 upvoters, how does it work? I forgot it myself and this looks counterintuitive, now that one and half years has past.

Comment: No idea what it's supposed to do, I'm confused :s

Comment: Does `Promise.resolve(value)` resolve a cloned `value`? I doubt it, past myself.

Comment: This doesn't do any cloning at all. Infact, it does nothing. This is equivalent to `const newObj = obj`.

Comment: Here is an article about cloning objects in javascript, https://cornerofcode.com/posts/clone-object-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

For a shallow copy there is a great, simple method introduced in ECMAScript2018 standard. It involves the use of *Spread Operator* :

```
let obj = {a : "foo", b:"bar" , c:10 , d:true , e:[1,2,3] };

let objClone = { ...obj };
```

I have tested it in Chrome browser, both objects are stored in different locations, so changing immediate child values in either will not change the other.  Though (in the example) changing a value in `e` will effect both copies.

This technique is very simple and straight forward. I consider this a true Best Practice for this question once and for all.

Comment: updating e in objClone will still update e in obj. This is still only a shallow copy. The question explicitly asks for a deep clone.

Comment: @Taugenichts... did you tested it? The method works perfectly. [Spread_syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `Spread in object literals` section

Comment: yes, I tested it. run this code: objClone.e[4] = 5; console.log(obj.e); You will see obj.e being updated

Comment: Because both are stored in different locations merely means it is at least a shallow copy.  Look at where `obj.e` and `objClone.e` are stored; you will find that they are stored in the same location.

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys@LupusOssorum @Taugenichts  for pointing this out. I tested it myself and found out what you guys identified here. But do you have any idea why the array still does not change memory, though ECMA2018 boasts of this as a feature.

Comment: From mozilla's docs on it under Spread in object literals: "Shallow-cloning (excluding prototype) or merging of objects is now possible using a shorter syntax than Object.assign()." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: Not a deep clone, not what OP asked for.

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution without using any library or native javascript function.

```
function deepClone(obj) {
  if (typeof obj !== "object") {
    return obj;
  } else {
    let newObj =
      typeof obj === "object" && obj.length !== undefined ? [] : {};
    for (let key in obj) {
      if (key) {
        newObj[key] = deepClone(obj[key]);
      }
    }
    return newObj;
  }
}
```

Comment: Careful... `const o = {}; o.a = o; deepClone(o);` -> recursion error.

Comment: Doesn't work for objects which happen to have a property called `length`, like `{ foo: "bar", length: "10cm" }`, as it doesn't infer arrays properly. Also, turns `{ foo: null }` into `{ foo: {} }`, because it doesn't check for null properly.

Answer (score 2):

Requires new-ish browsers, but...

Let's extend the native Object and get a **real** `.extend()`;

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'extend', {
    enumerable: false,
    value: function(){
        var that = this;

        Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).map(function(source){
            var props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(source),
                i = 0, l = props.length,
                prop;

            for(; i < l; ++i){
                prop = props[i];

                if(that.hasOwnProperty(prop) && typeof(that[prop]) === 'object'){
                    that[prop] = that[prop].extend(source[prop]);
                }else{
                    Object.defineProperty(that, prop, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, prop));
                }
            }
        });

        return this;
    }
});
```

Just pop that in prior to any code that uses .extend() on an object.

Example:

```
var obj1 = {
    node1: '1',
    node2: '2',
    node3: 3
};

var obj2 = {
    node1: '4',
    node2: 5,
    node3: '6'
};

var obj3 = ({}).extend(obj1, obj2);

console.log(obj3);
// Object {node1: "4", node2: 5, node3: "6"}
```

Comment: Mutating prototypes is generally considered bad practice, with the only exception being for shims.

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution with recursion:

```js
obj = {
  a: { b: { c: { d: ['1', '2'] } } },
  e: 'Saeid'
}
const Clone = function (obj) {
  
  const container = Array.isArray(obj) ? [] : {}
  const keys  = Object.keys(obj)
   
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    const key = keys[i]
    if(typeof obj[key] == 'object') {
      container[key] = Clone(obj[key])
    }
    else
      container[key] = obj[key].slice()
  }
  
  return container
}
 console.log(Clone(obj))
```

Comment: fails completely with a simple test of `[1,2]`

Answer (score 2):

When your object is nested and it contains data object, other structured object or some property object, etc then using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))` or `Object.assign({}, obj)` or `$.extend(true, {}, obj)` will not work. In that case use lodash. It is simple and easy..

```
var obj = {a: 25, b: {a: 1, b: 2}, c: new Date(), d: anotherNestedObject };
var A = _.cloneDeep(obj);
```

Now A will be your new cloned of obj without any references..

Answer (score 2):

if you find yourself doing this type of thing regular ( eg- creating undo redo functionality ) it might be worth looking into [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/)

```
const map1 = Immutable.fromJS( { a: 1, b: 2, c: { d: 3 } } );
const map2 = map1.setIn( [ 'c', 'd' ], 50 );

console.log( `${ map1.getIn( [ 'c', 'd' ] ) } vs ${ map2.getIn( [ 'c', 'd' ] ) }` ); // "3 vs 50"
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OBpqNE?editors=1111

Answer (score 2):

With the proposal of the new method [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) that is supported on newer versions of some browsers ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries#Browser_compatibility)). I want to contribute with the next recursive approach:

```js
const obj = {
  key1: {key11: "key11", key12: "key12", key13: {key131: 22}},
  key2: {key21: "key21", key22: "key22"},
  key3: "key3",
  key4: [1,2,3, {key: "value"}]
}

const cloneObj = (obj) =>
{
    if (Object(obj) !== obj)
       return obj;
    else if (Array.isArray(obj))
       return obj.map(cloneObj);

    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(
        ([k,v]) => ([k, cloneObj(v)])
    ));
}

// Clone the original object.
let newObj = cloneObj(obj);

// Make changes on the original object.
obj.key1.key11 = "TEST";
obj.key3 = "TEST";
obj.key1.key13.key131 = "TEST";
obj.key4[1] = "TEST";
obj.key4[3].key = "TEST";

// Display both objects on the console.
console.log("Original object: ", obj);
console.log("Cloned object: ", newObj);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

As this question is having lot of attention and answers with reference to inbuilt features such as Object.assign or custom code to deep clone, i would like to share some libraries to deep clone,

**1. esclone**

npm install --savedev esclone https://www.npmjs.com/package/esclone

Example use in ES6:

```
import esclone from "esclone";

const rockysGrandFather = {
  name: "Rockys grand father",
  father: "Don't know :("
};
const rockysFather = {
  name: "Rockys Father",
  father: rockysGrandFather
};

const rocky = {
  name: "Rocky",
  father: rockysFather
};

const rockyClone = esclone(rocky);
```

Example use in ES5:

```
var esclone = require("esclone")
var foo = new String("abcd")
var fooClone = esclone.default(foo)
console.log(fooClone)
console.log(foo === fooClone)
```

**2. deep copy**

npm install deep-copy
https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-copy

Example:

```
var dcopy = require('deep-copy')

// deep copy object 
var copy = dcopy({a: {b: [{c: 5}]}})

// deep copy array 
var copy = dcopy([1, 2, {a: {b: 5}}])
```

**3. clone-deep**

$ npm install --save clone-deep
https://www.npmjs.com/package/clone-deep

Example:

```
var cloneDeep = require('clone-deep');

var obj = {a: 'b'};
var arr = [obj];

var copy = cloneDeep(arr);
obj.c = 'd';

console.log(copy);
//=> [{a: 'b'}] 

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function clone(obj) {
    var copy;

    // Handle the 3 simple types, and null or undefined
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;

    // Handle Date
    if (obj instanceof Date) {
        copy = new Date();
        copy.setTime(obj.getTime());
        return copy;
    }

    // Handle Array
    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        copy = [];
        for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++) {
            copy[i] = clone(obj[i]);
        }
        return copy;
    }

    // Handle Object
    if (obj instanceof Object) {
        copy = {};
        for (var attr in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = clone(obj[attr]);
        }
        return copy;
    }

    throw new Error("Unable to copy obj! Its type isn't supported.");
}
```

use the following method instead of `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`  because 
it is slower than the following method

[How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 0):

How about merging the *keys* of the object with its *values*?

```
function deepClone(o) {
    var keys = Object.keys(o);
    var values = Object.values(o);

    var clone = {};

    keys.forEach(function(key, i) {
        clone[key] = typeof values[i] == 'object' ? Object.create(values[i]) : values[i];
    });

    return clone;
}
```

**Note:** *This method doesn't necessarily make shallow copies*, but it only copies with the depth of one inner-object, meaning that when you are given something like `{a: {b: {c: null}}}`, it will only clone the objects that are directly inside of them, so  `deepClone(a.b).c` is technically a reference to `a.b.c`, while `deepClone(a).b` is a clone, *not a reference*.

Comment: Not a deep clone. Only does one layer of depth. Also doesn't work for arrays or anything with the value `null` due to incorrect typeof checking.

Answer (score -5):

**Cloning an object using today's JavaScript: [ECMAScript 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015)** (formerly known as ECMAScript 6)

```
var original = {a: 1};

// Method 1: New object with original assigned.
var copy1 = Object.assign({}, original);

// Method 2: New object with spread operator assignment.
var copy2 = {...original};
```

Old browsers may not support ECMAScript 2015. A common solution is to use a JavaScript-to-JavaScript compiler like Babel to output an [ECMAScript 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#5th_Edition) version of your JavaScript code.

As [pointed out by @jim-hall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object-in-javascript?page=2&tab=oldest#comment60081951_36177142), **this is only a shallow copy**. Properties of properties are copied as a reference: changing one would change the value in the other object/instance.

Comment: This doesn't address deep merges. https://gist.github.com/jimbol/5d5a3e3875c34abcf60a

Comment: Wow, this answer is so wrong. Both your methods do a shallow copy of one level. Anyone looking at this answer, move on.